# bash: /etc/environment: Permission denied

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I am trying to run following command:

```
grep -q NDDSHOME /etc/environment || echo 'NDDSHOME="/opt/rti_connext_dds-6.0.1"' >> /etc/environment
```

But facing permission denied error:

```
bash: /etc/environment: Permission denied
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```bash
grep -q NDDSHOME /etc/environment || ( echo 'NDDSHOME="/opt/rti_connext_dds-6.0.1"' | sudo tee -a /etc/environment )
```

This file is owned by root, you can't just append to it.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to write to a system file `/etc/environment`  without having the privileges to do so.

Either run the entire command as root:

```
sudo -s
grep -q NDDSHOME /etc/environment || echo 'NDDSHOME="/opt/rti_connext_dds-6.0.1"' >> /etc/environment
```

Or make sure that the append `>>` is run as root (here we replace it with `tee` to append to the file, and then discard the *stdout* aspect):

```
grep -q NDDSHOME /etc/environment || echo 'NDDSHOME="/opt/rti_connext_dds-6.0.1"' | sudo tee -a /etc/environment >/dev/null
```